# Get activity onDestroy() in Recycler Adapter

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using a Handler to display a timer in `RecyclerView` list item. When I press back the `Activity` that hosts the `RecyclerView` is completely destroyed, the `Handler()` still running in the background. The handler is created and initiated in `ViewHolder`. Is there any way to remove the callbacks from handler from `ViewHolder` itself?

My ViewHolder sample code

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), CustomRunnable.CustomRunnableListener{

    private val handler = Handler()
    lateinit var customRunnable: CustomRunnable //custom runnable for my timer logic

    fun bind(position: Int, listModelClass: ModelClass?){


        if(someCondition){
                customRunnable = CustomRunnable(handler, this, textView, listModelClass)
                handler.postDelayed(customRunnable, 1000)
        }

    }

    override fun onTimerFinish(listModelClass: ModelClass) {
            // I get this call back when the timer finishes
            handler.removeCallbacks(customRunnable)
    }

}
```

Comment: Have all items timer?

Comment: Yeah. I have timer in all items

Comment: Could you paste your recycler view code?

Answer (score 1):

if your Activity extended from `androidx.activity.ComponentActivity`, you can do this easily, just bind the lifecycle event then the super class would done their job as your desired, the sample code like below:

```kotlin
internal class SampleViewHolder(
    private val activity: TheActivity,
    view: View
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    fun bind(item: SampleInfo, position: Int) {
        val view = itemView
        ...
        bindLifecycle()
    }

    fun onViewRecycled() {
        itemView.imv_sample.onViewRecycled(sampleAdapter.playStateStore)
        activity.lifecycle.removeObserver(lifecycleObserver)
    }

    private val lifecycleObserver = object : LifecycleObserver {
        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
        private fun onDestroy() {
            MLog.info(TAG, "receive destroy event")
            itemView.imv_sample.onHostActivityDestroyed()
        }
    }

    private fun bindLifecycle() {
        activity.lifecycle.run {
            MLog.info(TAG, "success bind lifecycle")
            addObserver(lifecycleObserver)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, there is no method on adapter that is called when `RecyclerView` is detached from activity.

Try creating a timer object or a list of objects in your `BaseActivity` or `Application` Class and after pressing onBack run a method that will stop that timer or timers.

```
//Declare timer
    CountDownTimer cTimer = null;

    //start timer function
    void startTimer() {
        cTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        };
        cTimer.start();
    }


    //cancel timer
    void cancelTimer() {
        if(cTimer!=null)
            cTimer.cancel();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it **onDestory()** of activity

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

> Remove any pending posts of callbacks and sent messages whose obj is token. If token is null, all callbacks and messages will be removed.

Comment: The scope of Handler only is within the ViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

When the activity is destroyed, set the list adapter to null. This will make sure **onViewDetachedFromWindow** is called for all the views in list when the activity is destroyed.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mList.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And then you can remove the callbacks from the handler running inside the viewHolder. This requires you to save the handler reference inside your viewHolder.

```
@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull PurchaseItemViewHolder holder) {
    if (holder.handler != null) {
        holder.handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
}
```